# How to plot geoJSON using Python?

Tags: python, geojson, visualisation

I have huge geojson file that I am working on:

```
[{
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        [-122.317273801854, 47.6190539780876],
                        [-122.317274348118, 47.6190828843557],
                        [-122.317292412364, 47.6190827204113],
                        [-122.317293657623, 47.6191487985433],
                        [-122.317278082047, 47.6191489300374],
                        [-122.317278784338, 47.6191861453792],
                        [-122.317169984271, 47.6191870880631],
                        [-122.317169940562, 47.6191850459535],
                        [-122.317086827577, 47.6191857617427],
                        [-122.317085902845, 47.6191365192538],
                        [-122.317071510628, 47.6191366437151],
                        [-122.31707075927, 47.6190968289847],
                        [-122.317087362271, 47.6190966841237],
                        [-122.317086589249, 47.6190556005469],
                        [-122.317273801854, 47.6190539780876]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "shape_area": 2396.7925901799999
        }
    }, {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        [-122.317399793439, 47.6193250237895],
                        [-122.317268032808, 47.6193260666162],
                        [-122.317267907013, 47.6193188900984],
                        [-122.317235727754, 47.6193191468267],
                        [-122.317235835777, 47.6193252636292],
                        [-122.317202753366, 47.6193255237007],
                        [-122.317202683689, 47.6193211879516],
                        [-122.317165343647, 47.6193214866782],
                        [-122.31716542561, 47.6193262532654],
                        [-122.317106308653, 47.6193267179723],
                        [-122.317104513919, 47.6192236738067],
                        [-122.317170427418, 47.6192231555825],
                        [-122.317170486246, 47.6192266013983],
                        [-122.317202638424, 47.6192263436369],
                        [-122.317202504834, 47.6192183838426],
                        [-122.317232834592, 47.619218149834],
                        [-122.317232910156, 47.6192226918802],
                        [-122.317270835738, 47.619222395323],
                        [-122.317270712945, 47.6192148144418],
                        [-122.317306203271, 47.6192145313754],
                        [-122.317306260026, 47.6192179042152],
                        [-122.317397927553, 47.6192171763912],
                        [-122.317399793439, 47.6193250237895]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "shape_area": 2752.8221201699998
        }
    }, {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        [-122.317115538357, 47.6194422596203],
                        [-122.317113899889, 47.6193992260741],
                        [-122.317134286447, 47.61939887043],
                        [-122.317133036969, 47.6193658360276],
                        [-122.317300816098, 47.6193629282286],
                        [-122.317302336577, 47.6194031302355],
                        [-122.31732481124, 47.6194027473298],
                        [-122.317325542627, 47.6194218364951],
                        [-122.317305340514, 47.619422179941],
                        [-122.317305978981, 47.619438958089],
                        [-122.317115538357, 47.6194422596203]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "shape_area": 1269.9362947300001
        }
    }]
```

I am trying to plot this data; I tried many libraries/ways to plot it.

- https://github.com/kjordahl/geopandas
- https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent

But every time I receive an error saying:

```
ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
```

Is there any way to plot geojson data? I have used D3/Leaflet before. I succeeded to plot this file.

Comment: You say you have plotted the data to D3/leaflet successfully.  So what other type of format are you trying to "plot" the points to?  A graphics file?  A desktop GIS?  Another GIS file format (ie- shapefile)?

Comment: I wanna plot the file on desktop application using Python .

Comment: You might give the [Kartograph.py](http://kartograph.org/) library a try.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to plot the data in a desktop GIS software like [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/), you need to make the data a "Feature Collection" as stated [here](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-collection-objects):

> Features in GeoJSON contain a geometry object and additional properties, and a feature collection represents a list of features.

Once I wrapped your GeoJSON code (above) with:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":

   <place your data as seen above here>

}
```

I had no problem loading the data into QGIS (tested).

Comment: Ryan's right. Your data wasn't valid.

Comment: Instead of QGIS you may also use http://geojson.io

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange!

You should try [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely):

From the doc, Shapely can plot geoJson objects:

```
    import json
    from shapely.geometry import mapping, shape

    s = shape(json.loads('{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [0.0, 0.0]}'))
    >>> s
    <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x...>

    print(json.dumps(mapping(s)))
    {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [0.0, 0.0]}
```

Comment: But the result is not a map ??

Comment: the result is a grid